# Show $f-g$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1 \}$ be the open unit disk on the complex plane. Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are complex valued analytic functions on $D$ such that $Re(f(z))=Re(g(z))$ for all $z$ in $D$. Show that $f-g$ is constant on $D$.

My approach: Let $f(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\bar az}$ and $g(z)=\frac{z-b}{1-\bar bz}$

Then do I show that $f(z)-g(z)$ is constant? Do I have the right approach? Thanks.

Comment: Consider the derivatives of $f-g$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $h(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ be a complex valued analytic function such that $\Re(h(z)) = 0$ for all $z$ in the domain (i.e. $u(x,y) = 0$).

It must be that $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ so we can determine that $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$. Similarly, it must be that $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ so we can determine that $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0$. This implies that $h(z)$ is constant.

So far we know that $\Re(h(z)) = 0$, $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0$ and $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$.

Suppose that $v(x,y)$ is real valued and defined on a domain $D$. Because $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0$, $v$ remains constant on any horizontal line segment in $D$. Similarly, $v$ is constant along any vertical line that lies in $D$. Because a domain must be open connected by definition, every two points is connected by a polygonal path which can be decomposed into a path of horizontal and vertical line segments. Because of this, the value of $v$ at any two points in $D$ is the same and $v(x,y)$ is constant.

Comment: Ah I see. So this problem was a consequence of cauchry reumann

Comment: Yes. In general, if $\operatorname{Re}(f(z)), \operatorname{Im}(f(z))$ or $|f(z)|$ is constant than $f(z)$ is constant by Cauchy-Riemann.

Comment: So where does this come in: $Re(f(z))=Im(g(z))$ on your answer? Is that just an indicator that these are constant therefore apply cauchy riemann?

Comment: I think you mean $\Re(f(z)) = \Re(g(z))$ and this means that when you subtract the two functions and obtain $f-g$, the real part of this is zero.

Comment: Ah yes sorry typo! I would have never came up with that myself. Thanks.